# List Virtual Machine in an azure site recovery plan

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-site-recovery

I need to add some pre/post action to an Azure Site Recovery plan against the vm in the recovery plan. I have the following code, however, no VMs are listed. Please what can I do to enhance the code.

```
param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Object]$RecoveryPlanContext
)


$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
$VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
Disconnect-AzAccount -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
Clear-AzContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
Disable-AzContextAutosave –Scope Process | Out-Null



# Login to Azure 
Connect-AzAccount -Identity

Write-Verbose "getting vmmap object"
$VMMapColl = $RecoveryPlanContextObj.VmMap

$VMCollection = @()

$VMinfo = $RecoveryPlanContext.VmMap | Get-Member | Where-Object MemberType -EQ NoteProperty | select -ExpandProperty Name
$vmMap = $RecoveryPlanContext.VmMap
    foreach($VMID in $VMinfo)
    {
        $VMCollection += $VM              
         
        }

$CollectionCount = $VMCollection.Count
Write-Output "Collection Count: $CollectionCount" 
#Returning Collection
$VMCollection.RoleName
```

Answer (score 0):

> List Virtual Machine in an azure site recovery plan

Here is the updated `PowerShell` script to list all **VMs** in the `Azure Site Recovery Plan`.

```
    $ResourceGroup = "<RG_name"
    $VaultName = "<vault_name>"
    # Get the ASR vault
    $vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $VaultName
    
    # Set the context of the vault. This is required for all future commands
    Set-AzRecoveryServicesAsrVaultContext -Vault $vault
    
    # List all the items that are in a protected state by friendly name and resource ID
    
    $fabrics = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrFabric
       
        
    foreach ($fabric in $fabrics) {
                $container = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectionContainer -Fabric $fabric
                $protectItem = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem -ProtectionContainer $container
                $RecoveryPlan = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrRecoveryPlan | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "Service_Plan_Name"}
    
            if ($protectedItem.RecoveryFabricId -eq $RecoveryPlan.TargetServerId){
    
            Write-Host "Virtual Machine Name: $($protectedItems.FriendlyName)"
            Write-Host "VM ID: $($protectedItems.ID)"
            Write-Host "Protection State: $($protectedItems.ProtectionState)"
            Write-Host "============================="
        }
      }
```

This `PowerShell` script will list all **VMs** in a `Service Plan` and then add `pre/post` actions to an `Azure Site Recovery plan` as per your requirement.

**Output:**

[image]

Reference:  [How do you get a list of all the VMs in a Recovery Plan with powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1572928/asr-how-do-you-get-a-list-of-all-the-vms-in-a-reco)

Comment: Hope this helps to resolve your query.

Comment: Thanks VenKat, I think the script is missing a loop in this part 
if ($protectedItem.RecoveryFabricId -eq $RecoveryPlan.TargetServerId){
       
               Write-Host "Virtual Machine Name: $($protectedItem.FriendlyName)"
               Write-Host "VM ID: $($protectedItem.ID)"
              Write-Host "Protection State: $($protectedItem.ProtectionState)"
             Write-Host "============================="
          }

Comment: Are you facing any issues with the script? Let me know, and I will check and correct it.